# How to sample random variables (x,y) from a bivariate Cauchy distribution using a Gibbs sampler?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, cauchy-distribution

A bivariate Cauchy distribution is equivalent to a bivariate t-distribution with 1 degree of freedom.

Comment: Why not generate Cauchy variates directly?  Is this homework?

Comment: It's a question from a past exam.

Comment: I can think of using the method of composition using the fact that the t-distribution can be written in terms of the ratio of a standard normal distribution and a chi-squared distribution. I can't figure how to do Gibbs sampling for the same problem...

Comment: Using the ratio is not Gibbs sampling.  For Gibbs sampling, you only need the density of the Cauchy distribution and some proposal distribution.  Do you know how Gibbs sampling works?

Comment: I know only the basics, that you sample at each step using the full conditional distributions i.e you sample $$x_i^{t+1}$$ from $$p(x_i|y, x_2^t,... x_n^t)$$ for i: 1 to n.

How does the proposal distribution come into play for Gibbs sampling? I don't know anything about that...

Comment: @NeilG I believe the purpose is to generate variables from the joint distribution. If you sample from the two marginals directly, you will miss the dependence.